# Iterate Feature Selection freezes in ArcGIS Pro 2.7

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, iterator

I'm recreating a model on ArcGIS Pro 2.7 that I have used in the past on ArcMap 10.7.1.  It is a model that takes a selected parcels layer, iterates through each selected parcel to find the addresses within them, and replaces the PIN in the address with the PIN in the parcel.

It works flawlessly in ArcMap, but for some reason, the *Iterate Feature Selection* function freezes upon starting in ArcGIS Pro.  I have created a very simple model that uses my selection of 3 parcels.  When I hit run, the model freezes at the *Iterate Feature Selection* process.  The only way to stop it is to Task Manager out of ArcGIS Pro.

I know we can still use ArcMap since it works there but would like to get it running on ArcGIS Pro as well. We have deleted and recreated the model and rebooted the workstation. No luck.

Any thoughts as to what is going on with ArcGIS Pro?

[image]

Comment: Has the input data changed  its format? Maybe try and reinstall arcpro?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but have you tried unchecking "skip null values"?
Also, if there is potentially a problem with the format of the feature layer, maybe do a fresh export into a geodatabase and see if that brings up any error or even fixes it.

Comment: I have uninstalled Pro, rebooted the computer, ran CCleaner, and reinstalled Pro.  Selected three different parcels in a different part of the county.  Created a simple model that just has the Iterate Feature Selection.  Still locks up when trying to run it with the "skip null values" checked and unchecked.